# How to change the default value of map

Tags: dictionary, go

I read that Go set values to "zero value" of the data type in map. I wonder if there is an easy way to set a different default value similar to the use of defaultdict in Python?

to clarify the question, here is the Python code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
from collections import defaultdict
prices=defaultdict(lambda:5) # default value 5 instead of 0
prices[2]=0
prices[3]=0
print(prices) # {2: 0, 3: 0}
for i,p in enumerate ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]):
    if p>prices[i]: 
    # if price is greater than existing price, compare to 5 when it doesn't exist 
        prices[i]=p
print(prices) # {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 6})
```

Comment: There is no way to change the default value, which makes code much more predictable.

Comment: @BurakSerdar "much more predictable" is an exaggeration for sure.

Comment: In general there is exactly 0 magic or customisation or overriding default behaviour in Go. If something has some default behaviour in Go it is typically not worth exploring ways to change it as there are none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the zero value but an easy way to simulate that is to wrap element access into a function which can return whatever you want to in case the key is not found:

```
var m = map[int]string{
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
}

func get(key int) string {
    if v, ok := m[key]; ok {
        return v
    }
    return "<missing>"
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(get(1))
fmt.Println(get(2))
fmt.Println(get(3))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cQl4gxa-ePd)):

```
one
two
<missing>
```

You can of course make it a method and usage may be more intuitive, and by putting it into a package and not exporting the map you ensure no one "bypasses" the getter method:

```
type mymap struct {
    m   map[int]string
    def string
}

func (m mymap) get(key int) string {
    if v, ok := m.m[key]; ok {
        return v
    }
    return m.def
}
```

And then using it:

```
m := mymap{
    m: map[int]string{
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
    },
    def: "<missing>",
}

fmt.Println(m.get(1))
fmt.Println(m.get(2))
fmt.Println(m.get(3))
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WNrORoKf_L9).